# Переустановка pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Если кратко то вот что произошло по каким-то причинам модуль pygame удалился сам по себе, пытался заново установить но ничего не получается

Comment: Как пытаетесь установить? Какую ошибку бросает? Под вопросом есть кнопка "Править". Воспользуйтесь ей, чтобы добавить эту информацию в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip install pygame в cmd
посмотри если есть остаточные файлы от него, то удали